# Custom UIGestureRecognizer: selector does not receive UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I am implementing custom UIGestureRecognizer. For simplicity, let assume that it recognizes gesture that consists of >1 touches.

Here is Gesture.m:

```
#import "Gesture.h"
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

#define SHOW printf("%s %d %d %d\n", __FUNCTION__, self.state, touches.count, self.numberOfTouches)

@implementation Gesture

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  SHOW;
  if (self.numberOfTouches==1) return;
  self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  SHOW;
  if (self.numberOfTouches==1) return;
  self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  SHOW;
  if (self.numberOfTouches==1) return;
  self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded;
}
@end
```

Here is a selector:

```
- (IBAction)handleGesture:(Gesture *)recognizer {
  printf("%s %d\n", __FUNCTION__, recognizer.state);
}
```

And here is an output:

```
-[Gesture touchesBegan:withEvent:] 0 1 1  // 1st touch began
-[Gesture touchesMoved:withEvent:] 0 1 1
-[Gesture touchesMoved:withEvent:] 0 1 1
-[Gesture touchesMoved:withEvent:] 0 1 1
-[Gesture touchesBegan:withEvent:] 0 1 2  // 2nd touch began
-[Gesture touchesMoved:withEvent:] 1 1 2  // Gesture.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan but selector was not called
-[ViewController handleGesture:] 2        // UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged received.
-[Gesture touchesMoved:withEvent:] 2 2 2
-[ViewController handleGesture:] 2
-[Gesture touchesMoved:withEvent:] 2 2 2
-[ViewController handleGesture:] 2
-[Gesture touchesMoved:withEvent:] 2 2 2
-[ViewController handleGesture:] 3        // UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded received.
```

Why doesn't selector receive UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't particularly obvious to me but the rules seem to be:

- all touches sent to you via `touchesBegan:...` are subsequently considered to belong to you unless and until you set the state to `UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed`, `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` or `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled`;
- if instead you transition to `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` then the gesture recogniser will post that on, then **automatically** generate `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` when the touches that are now assigned to you move.

So you're not supposed to set `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` for yourself — just keep track of the touches and correctly post began, ended, failed and cancelled.

In your case I think you just need to remove the state set within `touchesMoved:...`.

(aside: the above is true of iOS 5 and 6; under 4 the behaviour is slightly more subtle. To work under all three versions use a construction like `if(self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged;` when you know that your properties have changed)

Comment: I have just checked and, yes, you are completely right: commenting the line "self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged;" solved the problem! Thank you!